# Is the language L = { a^n b^j : j ≤ n ≤ 2j − 1 } context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-language

Is the language L = { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>j</sup> : j ≤ n ≤ 2j − 1 } context-free?
I have no idea how to start with this exercise. I am familiar with the pumping lemma, but I have no idea how I should use it here. It seems to me that this language is context-free and that something could be done with the stack to realise it, but I do not know how.
So if someone could give me a hint to start, I would highly appreciate it.

I took this exercise from the book 'Formal languages and automata', fifth edition, by Peter Linz, exercise 8.1.14

After some help in the comments, I thought of the following grammar:

S-> aSb|aaaSbb|λ

Comment: @Ronald Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @Progman What in those help pages specifically do you think applies to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim the language L is generated by the following context-free grammar G, with starting symbol *S* and an additional non-terminal *T*:

0. *S* ↦ `aa`*S*`b`
1. *S* ↦ `a`*T*`b`
2. *T* ↦ `a`*T*`b`
3. *T* ↦ ε (the empty string)

Showing this grammar is a valid presentation of the language will prove the language is context-free.

**Proof.** (L ⊆ G).  We notice that any *n* such that *j* ≤ *n* ≤ 2*j* − 1 can be written as a sum *n* = *j* + *k*, with 0 ≤ *k* < *j*.  We also notice the case *j* = 0 is impossible, because the condition then implies 0 ≤ −1.  To generate a string `a`<sup>*j*+*k*</sup>`b`<sup>*j*</sup> with 0 ≤ *k* < *j*, 1 ≤ *j*, we apply:

0. rule (0) *k* times, obtaining `a`<sup>2*k*</sup>*S*`b`<sup>*k*</sup>; then
1. rule (1) once, obtaining `a`<sup>2*k*+1</sup>*T*`b`<sup>*k*+1</sup>; then
2. rule (2) *j* − (*k* + 1) times, obtaining `a`<sup>*j*+*k*</sup>*T*`b`<sup>*j*</sup>, and finally
3. rule (3) once, obtaining the desired string `a`<sup>*j*+*k*</sup>`b`<sup>*j*</sup>.

Therefore every string of L is generated by G.

(G ⊆ L; sketch).  By induction over grammar rules.  Observe that every string G can generate has the form `a`<sup>n</sup>*Z*`b`<sup>j</sup> where *n*, *j* ∈ ℕ, and *Z* is a non-terminal or the empty string.  Then observe that:

- at the start, we have *Z* = *S* and *n* = *j* = 0;
- rule (0) can only be applied when *Z* = *S*, it maintains *Z* = *S* and the invariant *n* = 2*j*;
- rule (1) can only be applied when *Z* = *S*, it sets *Z* = *T* and *n* = 2*j* − 1, which satisfies the invariant of L that *j* ≤ *n* < 2*j*;
- rule (2) can only be applied when *Z* = *T*, it maintains *Z* = *T* and the invariant of L, and
- rule (3) can only be applied when *Z* = *T*, it sets *Z* = ε and otherwise also maintains the invariant of L.

The only way to eliminate non-terminals is to pass rule (3), and that can be only applied after rule (1).  Therefore every string generated by G belongs to L.

As such, L and the language generated by G are the same language.  Because G is a context-free grammar, the language L is context-free. ∎